# convert from avi to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

I want to play an `avi` video format file in browsers using HTML5 video code. Since the 
`avi` format file doesn't play in browsers i have to convert it into mp4 format file.

For conversion i am using the `ffmpeg` code in Windows.

`ffmpeg -i  input.avi   OUTPUT.mp4`

The conversion of video is completed but the video codec and audio codec isn't valid thus it fails to play to play using video tag in `html5`.

Please find me proper code which coverts the file.
another conversion code i tried was.. `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -b:a 128k  OUTPUTAVINew.mp4` but i got error as libfaac unknown encoder 
please help me out and even i downloaded the `**libfaac.dll**` but didn't work out
        `

Comment: Find a video that _does_ work, then encode your videos with the same codecs, simples. To get info, use the following cmd `ffmpeg -i mymovie.avi`, where `mymovie.avi` is replaced with the name of your video.

Answer (score 19):

Old, but this post comes up tops in searches so...

ffmpeg should easily convert from avi to mp4 *without re-encoding*. (Do *not* specify new codecs!)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

Should also mention that batch conversions run most reliably when the script contains static data with each ffmpeg call on a new line (as opposed to having the script generate each call dynamically using variables).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get this error: `[mp4 @ 0x5556f084afc0] Could not find tag for codec v210 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

Comment: @RaleighL. that error appears to be caused by an anomaly in the avi file (but no time to look up 'v210' ATM to verify). If avi file is valid, might have to first convert to an alternate format, then to mp4 (if desired).

Answer (score 5):

code to avi to mp4.ffmpeg provides the best solution

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Comment: The question asker already tried that (besides properly omitting the unneeded `-strict -2`). What does your answer do any differently?

Comment: This worked for me and my wacky AVI file when the upvoted answer did not

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the latest version of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z). You don't
 need to download extra dlls.

Use `libvo_aacenc` instead of `libfaac`

`-crf 22` is high use lower say `-crf 19`

As far my experience I would use

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k
```

Answer (score 0):

For example there is a video file 139MB input.avi

```
ffprobe input.avi
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf51.12.1
  Duration: 00:21:20.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 891 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (xvid / 0x64697678), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 769 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s
```

For the nearly loseless re-containering use:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -c:v copy -c:a copy "input.mp4"
```

where `-c:v copy` copy video
`-c:a copy` copy audio

Conversion about 2 sec, result is input.mp4 138MB. It is fast, and almost same quality as original. **Best practice is let the audio in the original format.**

```
ffprobe input.mp4
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:21:20.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 884 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 769 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

If you have time, and want to recodec almost same quality, but 1/3 size, use this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -c:a copy -c:v vp9 -b:v 100K "input.vp9.mp4"
```

where `-c:a copy` copy audio `-c:v vp9 -b:v 100K` re-encode video with 100K bitrate. 138MB re-encoding takes about 40min and the new file size is 41MB the quality is nearly same as original, but pixeled a bit.

```
ffprobe input.vp9.mp4
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:21:20.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 261 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp9 (Profile 0) (vp09 / 0x39307076), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 640x480, 146 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```